# EventToCommand missing in Blend

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, mvvm-light, blend

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 (I just updated it to RC1 - in hopes of resolving this problem) on a windows 8.1 release and I do not have the EventToCommand behavior in Blend (ie. Assets>Behaviors)?  I only get the InovkeCommandAction behavior.  I installed MVVM Light using the standard way (Tools > Extensions and Updates > Mvvm Light for VS2015) and all seemed to work fine; that is I now get the option to create a MVVM Light WPF 451 project.  I should also mention that in my project, I target the .NET 4.6 framework (the latest), although I've also tried 4.5, 4.52 and they had the same problem.  Also worthy of a note, if I program in the EventToCommand in xaml it spits errors at me [cannot add instance of type eventtrigger to a collection of type triggercollection. Only items of type T are allowed], but the program works.  The error however sometimes prevents me from being able to view the xaml in the Design view, not always though.

Any help is greatly appreciated
Doug

Comment: You have some component targeting System.Windows.Interactivity 4.0. You need to check your installed .Net Framework, and update the reference to target of System.Windows.Interactivity 4.5 only.

Comment: I have the following System.Windows.Interactivity Reference in my Reference section of my WPF MVVM Light project:
Runtime Version v4.0.30319 version 4.5.0.0